# Define the width of a logic puzzle dynamically

Tags: pdftex, minipage, scaling, width, logicpuzzle

I want a PDF page to fit a logic puzzle completely (cropped), but I do not know the resulting width when beginning the block for the puzzle:

```
\documentclass[border=50px]{standalone}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\begin{document}
  \begin{fourwinds}[rows=50,columns=50,width=750px,scale=0.5]
    \framepuzzle
    \fourwindscell{1}{1}{2}{}
    \fourwindscell{50}{50}{2}{}
  \end{fourwinds}
\end{document}
```

I want to calculate the width `750px` dynamically. The documentation of `logicpuzzle` says this is the width of the minipage which will surround the puzzle. But I did not found an option to set the width of a minipage dynamically.

Is there a way of adjusting the width of a minibox after it has been "created" to a new width? And can I get the width of a minipage which describes how much pixels would be needed to display the whole content?

It is possible to calculate the resulting width before creating the puzzle like `width=<number of columns * width of one column>`? And it is possible to get the width of one column from the `logicpuzzle` package?

I could not find a `varwidth` option for the `logicpuzzle` package which would be exactly what I need...

Comment: What do you mean by “calculate the width 750px” dynamically? Pixel means nothing in TeX's world.

Comment: If I change the puzzle size I have to change the width of the minipage to, but how do I know that 750px would be enough to contain the content? I want the PDF page to shrink to the puzzle size, but the PDF page shrinks currently to the size of the minipage which is a fixed size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`logicpuzzle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle) does **not** offer a possibilty to define an exact `width` or `height` of a puzzle, as the actual size of the puzzle can always overshoot the given `width` of the `minipage`! But you can of course always use `\resizebox` to define the `width` or `height` of an `object`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\begin{document}
  \resizebox{8cm}{!}
  {
    \begin{fourwinds}[rows=50,columns=50,width=10cm,scale=0.2,fontsize=tiny]
      \framepuzzle
      \fourwindscell{1}{1}{2}{}
      \fourwindscell{50}{50}{2}{}
    \end{fourwinds}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe image]

As `egreg` already noted, `750 px` (Pixel) does not make any sense in context of a vector format like `PDF`, so simply specify a with in `cm` or any other `LaTeX` unit.

The standard `width` of a column is 1 cm. Therefore you can approximately calculate the `width` of the puzzle with `columns * 1cm * scale`, e.g. `50*1cm*0.2 = 10cm`! In the log you will find, that `10cm` is a bit too small: `Overfull \hbox (4.37386pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--12 [][]`

Bear in mind, that using `\resizebox` all over the place might result in different font sizes in the puzzles, which might not look very pleasant! Using a fixed set of `fontsize` and `scale` might be the best option, but maybe difficult for puzzles with hugely different sizes.

Comment: The information about one column having a width of 1 cm is exactly what I needed! Now I can calculate the width of the puzzle. Thanks!